# HTML canvas editor

Tags: html, looking-for-a-script, canvas

I'd like to implement a very simplistic image editor (similar to http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/) on my website, so that users can have a trivial playground. Say I have a black and white sketch (png) that I want to let them color.

In theory I could develop the entire thing using `canvas`, but I'm hoping something like that is already developed. All I need is "paint brush" tool and "fill bucket" tool … that's it.

This is the closest I found, though I think it's not the best implementation: http://athousandnodes.com/labs/canvasFun/

Are there known better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Though I've never had to try what you're asking, Picasa uses Picnik for photo editing. The API for use on your website is at http://www.picnik.com/info/api .

Comment: I think Google closed Picnik down a few years ago (reported in Jan 2012)? http://readwrite.com/2012/01/20/google_to_close_picnik_social_graph_api_making_way